# Why Object reference not set to an instance of an object is thrown while creating Custom Alerts in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

         SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        btn.Click += delegate
          {
              var popup = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

              var btncamera = popup.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
              builder.SetView(Resource.Layout.popup);
              builder.Show();

              btncamera.Click += delegate
                {
                    builder.Dispose();
                };

          };

    }
```

Thank You

---

[image]

Comment: Click "Break" then use the debugger to figure out which specific line and variable are causing the null ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong way

so change your this code

```
btn.Click += delegate
          {
              var popup = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

              var btncamera = popup.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
              builder.SetView(Resource.Layout.popup);
              builder.Show();

              btncamera.Click += delegate
                {
                    builder.Dispose();
                };

          };
```

to this way

```
btn.Click += delegate
          {
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
              LayoutInflater inflater = this.LayoutInflater;
              var dialogView = inflater.inflate(Resource.Layout.linearLayout1, null);
              builder.SetView(dialogView);
              var btncamera = builder.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
              builder.Show();

              btncamera.Click += delegate
                {
                    builder.Dispose();
                };

          };
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me

Comment: @SandeepSaini if that work for you then you can mark answer as accept so it help other.